# Removing GRUB completely

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I'm trying to uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 from a dual boot config. I deleted all partitions used by it. There was one partition called OEM partition (A second one, pretty sure Ubuntu made this). I deleted this using EaseUS Partition master.

I made a Windows 8.1 boot USB, used the repair CMD, and tried `/fixboot` and `/fixmbr`. I also changed the boot order to windows and deleted ubuntu from the boot order.

I have a strong feeling GRUB's not done with me yet. Is this correct?

The main reason I uninstalled Ubuntu was to make Windows run faster. I do not want to sacrifice on Windows' speed. I do not want to get into technicalities, but how do I remove Ubuntu ***completely***? (This includes everything else it installed : GRUB, GRUB rescue, etc, etc).

I want to remove every last trace of my Ubuntu installation that reduces the performance of Windows.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that Grub still exists on your system after the commands you have run.

Of-course, Grub will not slow down your system.

Having Linux in a dual boot scenario will not slow your system down unless its causing your disk to be more then 80% full.  This is because Linux is not running so its not taking any memory or CPU resources.

The best way to "get rid of Linux completely" would be to boot up with a Linux boot disk and issue a command like "dd if/dev/zero of=/dev/sda"  (assuming /dev/sda is your hard disk).  This will take a while and will overwrite the entire disk - partition table and everything with 0 characters.  Realistically you could do "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=10240 count=102400" or similar which will be a lot quicker and only overwrite the first part of the disk - which includes the boot sector and partition tables for all partitions - you would then reinstall Windows from scratch.   Of-course, this is total overkill.

You have not advised the boot method you are using.   I do wonder if you have removed GRUB but are using UEFI - in which case you may be getting a Linux boot prompt - but this is not coming from the Operating system its coming from the BIOS.   [OS Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) is aUSB boot disk which should allow you to fully remove Linux including the UEFI stuff.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I have uefi. I'll have to check. It's a pretty modern laptop. Asus. 2 months old. I'll confirm first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: agreed. I have over 5 entries in my bootloader(s) containing 5 operating systems. None of them being installed affect the prformance of any other

Comment: Just checked, my PC does use UEFI. How does this change things?

Comment: Try using OS Uninstaller.  (I've never used it, but I'd imagine it will solve the problem for you). UEFI (in laymans terms) means that the boot options are kept partially in the BIOS, so to get rid of a "Linux" option when booting you need to clear it from the UEFI boot list.  Google "uefi clear boot entry" for more info.